# Wipe-on oil based poly fumes dangerous?

Tags: woodworking, polyurethane, hardwood-refinishing, refinishing, voc

So I refinished a table and did only 3 coats of mines wipe-on oil based satin poly, the temp has been colder here in AZ and it would only get to 75 Fahrenheit during the day then drop to 55-60 during the night.
I left the table in the garage for around 12 days before bring it in the house, however I can still smell some fumes coming off it if you sit down and get really close.

How dangerous is it to have these fumes?

I open the Arcadia door that it sits next to everyday and have an air purifier running right next to it. But honestly, I’m starting to wish I had used water-based or gone for something that has no VOCs even if it’s less durable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a chemist or a doctor, but I finish almost exclusively with poly and some scent remaining at point blank range is normal especially if you kept it in an enclosed space.

It will dissipate over the next week or two and you won't be able to smell it.

I don't think there is an immediate danger or risk of long term effects at this point of curing, but I wouldn't keep your nose next to it over this period of time.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I’m just extra paranoid because I have a toddler as well.

Comment: Don't worry about it. We all grew up with Model Cement  for plastic  and we're OK.